# Remote Debugging Tomcat8

Tags: intellij-idea, tomcat8

What is the process for setting up a Tomcat8 instance for remote debugging with IntelliJ? I am using the release which was pulled from aptitude and am unsure where to place the java options to enable me to connect to it using the debugger. I have tried quite a few locations to no avail.

Also, if there are any recent tutorials explaining this please let me know. All of the ones which are readily available seem to be out of date.

Comment: Do you mean that Tomcat no longer takes `JAVA_OPTS` from `/etc/default/tomcat8`?

Comment: That did it! I was trying to add the run options into the actual service script and the catalina.sh. Completely forgot about the /etc/default/tomcat8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat on Ubuntu takes `JAVA_OPTS` from `/etc/default/tomcat8` file.